# How to bind a dynamically created input element to a FormGroup?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a hierarchical object that describes a not very simple layout with input fields and etc, something like this:

```
{
  "type": "HorizontalLayout",
  "margin": false,
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "TextField",
      "id": "code",
      "caption": "Code of product",
      "width": "100px"
    },
    {
      "type": "NumberField",
      "id": "amount",
      "caption": "Amount of pieces"
    }
  ]
}
```

This object is not of a fixed depth, it can consist of many nested containers and input fields. It is not very difficult to render the object as a DOM fragment with all needed elements and append it to the desired element, but how can i then bind rendered inputs to the existing FormGroup?

Update: more specifically - how to bind an input element created with `document.createElement` to an existing `FormGroup`?

Comment: are you looking to create multiple FormGroups? or create a hierarchical FormGroup with child formGroups for each field, to allow you to obtain the state of all fields in the form?

Comment: @Edward, it will be a single flat FormGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i ended up creating input elements in a template of a component. This component is recursively created for every node of the layout object (as described in an [article of Ben Nadel](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3513-playing-with-recursive-components-in-angular-6-1-10.htm) (who deserves many virtual thanks for it)). An instance of FormGroup is explicitly passed to all the NodeComponent/NodeTreeComponent, which makes it easy to bind input elements to it.

Example of an object that describes layout:

```
{
  "type": "Container",
  "id": "filter",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "HorizontalLayout",
      "spacing": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "TextField",
          "id": "code",
          "caption": "Code",
          "width": "100px"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextField",
          "id": "label",
          "caption": "Name",
          "width": "200px"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextField",
          "id": "days",
          "caption": "Days",
          "width": "100px"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextField",
          "id": "months",
          "caption": "Months",
          "width": "100px"
        },
        {
          "type": "Check3Box",
          "id": "isActive",
          "caption": "Active",
          "height": "20px",
          "alignment": "bottom_left"
        },
        {
          "type": "Check3Box",
          "id": "isAbsDeleted",
          "caption": "Deleted from ABS",
          "height": "20px",
          "alignment": "bottom_left"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Part of main.component.html

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="filterForm">
    <form [formGroup]="my_awesome_form">
        <my-tree [rootNode]="elements" [form]="my_awesome_form"></my-tree>
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

Part of main.component.ts

```
// form creation
public my_awesome_form = new FormGroup({});

// saving a layout object to a public variable
public elements = some_data_service.getLayout();

// getting input fields from the layout object
const inputs = Utils.deepFind(this.elements, 'caption', '');

// binding inputs to form
inputs.forEach((input) => {
    this.filterForm.addControl(input.id, new FormControl(null));
});
```

TreeComponent

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {LayoutElement} from "@toolkit/models/layout.model";
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-tree",
  inputs: [
    "rootNode",
    "form"
  ],
  outputs: [],
  template: `<my-tree-node [node]="rootNode" [form]="form"></my-tree-node>`
})
export class TreeComponent {
  public rootNode: LayoutElement | null;
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.rootNode = null;
  }
}
```

TreeNodeComponent

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {LayoutElement} from "@toolkit/models/layout.model";
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-tree-node",
  inputs: [
    "node",
    "form"
  ],
  outputs: [],
  template:
      `
      <ng-template [ngIf]="node && node.type">
          <span [ngSwitch]="node.type" [formGroup]="form">
              <div *ngSwitchCase="'Container'">
                  <div *ngIf="node.children">
                      <ng-template ngFor let-child [ngForOf]="node.children">
                          <my-tree-node [node]="child" [form]="form"></my-tree-node>
                      </ng-template>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'TextField'">
                  <input type="text" [attr.placeholder]="node.caption" [formControlName]="node.id"/>
              </ng-template>
              <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                  <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">Element of type "{{ node.type }}" can't be processed!</div>
              </div>
          </span>
      </ng-template>
    `
})
export class TreeNodeComponent {
  public node: LayoutElement | null;
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.node = null;
  }
}
```

Thanks for everyone who tried to help! And btw sorry for such large code chunks, i didnt find how to insert spoilers

Answer (score 0):

Create a FormGroup in your class and recursively loop through each item in the children array then add a new control to the form.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2hep8) is a quick sample of how this can be done given that you're looking to have all controls at the same level in the FormGroup. the HTML shows the form RawValues so you can see what your form looks like in HTML.

In this example the 'data' property is fixed, but you could modify this and pass some other data into the setupForm method.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  form: FormGroup;
  data: {} = {
    "type": "HorizontalLayout",
    "margin": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "type": "TextField",
        "id": "code",
        "caption": "Code of product",
        "width": "100px"
      },
      {
        "type": "NumberField",
        "id": "amount",
        "caption": "Amount of pieces",
      }
    ]
  };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.fb.group({});
    // pass the data form which form controls should be created
    this.setupForm(this.data);
  }

  setupForm(field: any){
    if(field.children && field.children.length){
        const children = field.children;
        // Loop through each item in the children array and add a form control
        for(const item of children){
          // This assumes that all your fields have unique Ids
          this.form.addControl(item.id, new FormControl('test', [Validators.required]))
          // Process nested fields 
          this.setupForm(item);
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

The sample data you provided has the top level as an object. I suspect you may have multiple "HorizontalLayout". if that is the case you can modify the setupForm to process an array instead of an object.

The setupForm will also look for 'children' property and recursively call setupForm. this allows you to have multiple levels of nesting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've took a look at your example and found no actual input elements there. I know how to create a FormGroup, the main difficulty is to create input elements and bind to the existing FormGroup.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

dynamicForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    // set the fieldNames variable to generate form
    const fieldNames = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];

    this.dynamicForm = this.generateForm(fieldNames );
}

generateForm(fieldNames: string[]): FormGroup { // this is your form group
    const formFields: any = { };

    fieldNames.forEach(name=> {
        formFields[name] = [null, [Validators.required]];
    });

    return this.formBuilder.group(formFields);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, but where are creation of input elements? They are not in the template, they should be added dynamically. And that's the main difficulty

Comment: You can pass `fieldNames` to this method parameter which in this answer.And then the formGroup will return. You can assign this method result to any object where you want to assign.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use `dynamicForm` variable in HTML `<form>` tag too.

Comment: sorry i still don't understand how do you create elements) In your example i see only creation of a FormGroup, not the creation of input elements.